# Problems with OG "like" button for articles: not showing images/article contents in feeds

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have 2 like buttons on my site, one for the website itself is working fine, but the other one for the 'specific articles' isn't showing the image and article contents in the news feeds. It'll just show something like this:

Felix Tan likes a link.
http://www.neptuni.com/lab/blog/new-marketplace-new-opportunities.php

I believe this is a problem with my meta tags, here's my tags for the article page

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.neptuni.com/images/fb_image.png" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Neptuni.com" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Neptuni.com" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="514526208" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.neptuni.com/lab/blog/new-marketplace-new-opportunities.php" />
<meta property="og:description" content="test" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

You can see the specific page at http://www.neptuni.com/lab/blog/new-marketplace-new-opportunities.php

Answer (score 0):

It worked just fine for me. Most likely it's a caching problem. When facing such issues always run your links on the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).